# Python error message: builtins.IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

I am creating a game where the program will read from a file that contains 5 multiple choice questions and the user can answer this questions and receive a score. However I am getting stuck as I get the same error message:

```
builtins.IndexError: string index out of range
```

here is my code so far:

```
def main():
    playagain = True
    while playagain:
        inFile = open('Questions.txt', 'r')
        condition = True
        while condition:
            for line in range(5):
                line = inFile.readline()
                print(line)

            anskey = inFile.readline()
            anskey = anskey[4]

            status = True
            while status:
                useranswer = str(input('Enter your answer?  '))
                useranswer = useranswer.upper()

                if useranswer == 'A' or useranswer == 'B' or useranswer \
                    == 'C' or useranswer == 'D':
                    status = False
                    if useranswer == anskey:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        print('Correct Answer!')
                    else:
                        print('Wrong Answer!')
                        correct = correct
                else:
                    print('Answer not valid!')


main()
```

Comment: Post the _full traceback_ as an edit to your question (not as a comment!)

Comment: What line is this happening on? Details!

Comment: @eryksun - my mistake - I used PythonTidy to clean up the code formatting and it must have stripped out the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's only one index operation in your code, at `anskey[4]`, my guess is that your inFile has a line that has less than 5 characters on it.